# get results from HTML table with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Using the following code how could I parse an html table result? An example of the html can be found more forward.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
import StringIO

def http_request():

    try:
        url = "http://somehost/somehtml.html"
        r = requests.get(url, auth=("theUser", "thepass"))
        r.encoding ='ISO-8859-1'
        html = r.content
        parse_result(html)
    except requests.HTTPError, e:
        return False
        sys.exit(1)

def parse_result(result):
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(result), parser)

    # Here should be the logic to parse the html result :)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_request()
```

*This is the html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>name</B></td>
    <td>result name a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>inUse</B></td>
    <td>false</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>name</B></td>
    <td>result name b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>inUse</B></td>
    <td>false</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>name</B></td>
    <td>result name c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><B>inUse</B></td>
    <td>true</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the expected result would retrieve the **name** and the **inUse** field results, which is "result name" and "false".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the html you're pulling in has exactly that format:

```
nodes = etree.XPath("/html/body/table")
for node in nodes(tree):
    print '%s %s' % (node[0][1].text, node[1][1].text)
```

From your sample html, that outputs:

```
result name a false
result name b false
result name c true
```

If the format is going to vary outside of the sample html, you're likely going to have to be more creative with your [XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) and add more input checks.

Comment: Hi,

The main difference from the real example its the ammount of name and inuse outputs. there is more than 200 results.

Comment: Does it hold the same form where the `inUse` row comes after the `name` row for all results?

Comment: Im gonna uptade the question by adding more entries into the table